# 'NullInjectorError: No provider for t!' error with @ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an **angular 12.0.2** app that uses **ngrx 12.0.0**. When I run the app and access the route that lazy loads the module, I get the following error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(t)[t -> InjectionToken @ngrx/effects Feature Effects -> [object Object] -> t -> t -> t -> t -> t -> t]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(t)[t -> InjectionToken @ngrx/effects Feature Effects -> [object Object] -> t -> t -> t -> t -> t -> t]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
    at fs.get (main.js:1)
```

[image]

I have correctly set up the **ngrx** and **effects**. Please see the code below that shows the **effect**. The `UserService` is an entry in the **provider** in the module.

The error does not say which **provider** is missing. This is not a production build, but a build in my laptop to test.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Observable, EMPTY, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, debounceTime, map, switchMap, withLatestFrom, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as UserActions from '../actions/user.actions';
import { VisitorService } from '../../service/visitor.service';
import { asyncScheduler } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {

  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
    private userService: UserService) { }

  loadUsers$ = createEffect(
    () => ({ debounce = 300, scheduler = asyncScheduler } = {}) => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(UserActions.loadUsers),
        debounceTime(debounce, scheduler),
        switchMap((_) => {
          return this.userService.getUserss().pipe(
            map(users => (UserActions.loadUsersSuccess({ data: users }))),
            catchError(err => of(UserActions.loadUsersFailure(err)))
          );
        })
      );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to get a detailed error containing the missing provider you need to add `"optimization": false` option in the architect section of angular.json as follows:

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "optimization": false,
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The error 'No Provider for xyz' usually is thrown if you do not provide something or you do not call the `forRoot()` method on a module

In your case, Check how you have declared the Effect. Below is a sample of how it should look like

```
imports: [
  EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
]
```

If your feature is lazily loaded

```
imports: [
  EffectsModule.forFeature([Feature1Effects, Feature2Effects]),
]
```

Comment: I have ```EffectsModule.forFeature([UserEffects])``` in the import section of the **module**.

Comment: What about  EffectsModule.forRoot([]), in the app.module ?

Comment: I have ```StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }), !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [], EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects])```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was fixed after to added this in my @NgModule :

```
  exports: [HttpClientModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was routing missing in the app that was using a service that uses routing. But the problem was I couldn't see a proper error message because it was production build. So don't forget to switch to dev build first thing when getting messages like this, cuz I somehow forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we need to add provider in the module

```
providers: [
    serviceName
  ]
```